# Python Twisted application breaks when ntp updates time

Tags: python, twisted

I have a python application that makes extensive use of Twisted. I am in the process of migrating from python 2.5 to 2.7 as well as updating libraries and modules including going from Twisted 2.5 to 12.2. Looking through the code, there was some monkey-patching done in order to work around an issue where if the system time changed suddenly (like first ntp update), callLater and some other methods would have unexpected behavior (depending of time went forward or backwards).

Our work around at the time of twisted 2.5 was to redefine some methods with custom ones that returned monotonic time. Since then, it seems maybe some behavior in twisted has changed to account for this and broke our work around. I see several threads discussing related issues:

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/1396

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/2424

I see several patches floating around, but not sure if they were actually accepted. I am wondering if anyone has experience with this. Is there a way to enable monotonic time in Twisted?

Comment: While waiting to see if Glyph replies :-) I'll just say if you're looking for a purely monotonic time you may have to find a network source for TAI (international atomic time or terrestrial atomic time).  Unix time is not monotonic because on a leap second, the value repeats.

Comment: I don't know if monotomic is the correct word here, basically I just don't want callLaters to be affected by system time changes. So really it could be simply number of seconds of uptime for example.

Comment: there is a proposal and a sample (the linux part is ok, the windows part misses something) http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/

Answer (score 1):

The status of both of those tickets are "new", so, no, they haven't been fixed.

This is why you should contribute your bug-fixes upstream to your open-source dependencies, and participate in these long-running difficult bugs.  When you get around to updating, you'll want your issues to have been fixed :).

Better late than never - I look forward to seeing your contributions to #2424 and #1396 :).